# basic-auth in Express for static html pages

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication, password-protection

I want to password protect my website that is using Express for node.js I thought the right way was to use `basic-auth` module but this seems to work only for specific routes. For instance, if I have a page in the `public` folder, this will not be protected.

Do I need to specify the root for every single page in my site in order to password protect the whole website with snippets like the following?

```
app.get('/', auth, function (req, res) {
  res.send(200, 'Authenticated');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `auth` is the basic auth module?

```
app.use(auth);
```

that one line should go above the other app.use calls that load up your routes, your static ("public") folder, etc.

```
app.use(auth);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(myRouter);
app.use("/foo", anotherRouter);
// ... etc.
```